access http-only cookies via javascript from php
I have a laravel function for login which creates a sanctum token once successful:
public function attempt(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (auth()->attempt(array_merge($validated, ['status' => '1']))) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $user = auth()->user();
        $token = $user->createToken('sanctum-token')->plainTextToken;

        return redirect('/horseinfo')->with('message', __('errors.success'))->cookie('api_token', $token, 60, null, null, false, true);
    }

    return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'invalid email.'])->onlyInput('email');
}

Security isn't really my strength. Now, I've read that the token should be stored in an HTTP-only cookie to prevent JavaScript from accessing it. How can I get the cookie containing the token securely so I can access API routes with Sanctum auth when JavaScript cannot access the cookie?
my js has separate file. is it safe to add script on a blade template?
I am using fetch API to access api routes and have no idea how to get the token.

Not giving you access to the cookie in client-side JavaScript code, is the point of HttpOnly. Your own code doesn't need access - fetch itself will send the cookie. But if your request is cross-origin, you need to set credentials in your request options appropriately.

thank you for your answer. I've confirmed this since the fetch api on the same server doesn't require token but when used in another API handling software, it requires authentication.
